# How to block a specific email address domain from being able to submit Drupal webform?

Tags: drupal-webform

I've been trying to find an answer to as per title. How can I block a specific email address domain from being able to submit Drupal webform?

**Example:**

Webform has fields:

*Name, Email address, Subject, Query* - all fields are set to required.

What I want is a webform submission to be blocked when a visitor is trying to submit it using a specific email address domain, for example *@example.com.

I need my Drupal webform to be able to act similarly to a registration form equipped with [User restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) module.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was not aware that my question was a possible duplicate. The solution is [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module which was suggested by [Shawn Conn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45675/shawn-conn) at [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228682/how-to-block-a-specific-email-address-domain-from-being-able-to-submit-drupal-we?noredirect=1#comment280218_228682).

Thank you Shawn.